# How To Stop Recording Speech When User Stops Speaking With Swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2, ios9, avfoundation

I used `AVFoundation - AVAudioRecorder - AVAudioPlayer` with `Swift 2` and created a simple voice recorder. Currently you stop recording with a Stop button. Is it possible to stop recording when user stops speaking? Something like Siri. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is using the Audio Level Metering of the AVAudioRecorder.  I've never tried it, so I'm not sure how accurate it will be, or how sensitive to background noise.

I would look at this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioRecorder/averagePowerForChannel:

As per the documentation, averagePowerForChannel returns

> The current average power, in decibels, for the sound being recorded. A return value of 0 dB indicates full scale, or maximum power; a return value of -160 dB indicates minimum power (that is, near silence).

As you start recording, I'd sample this value for a period of a second or two and average it out which gives you a background noise level.

While the user is talking, the volume should go up from this.

Continue to monitor this value and then when it returns to some range within the background level for a second or so, turn the recording off.

It's probably not as accurate as Siri (which presumably does more processing, and potentially voice detection), but it might be good enough for your purposes.

The challenge will be working out the difference between the background level and the talking volume and what the sensitivity is - if they are close, it might not work well.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to use the monitoring idea successfully and it worked pretty well. I can provide code on how I did it.

However, it's not 100% foolproof since it can be thrown off by ambient noise when creating the baseline or after the user quits speaking. You still need to have a way to manually stop the recording in case the "auto-stop" doesn't work.

I found that a better and more reliable solution is using a "press and hold" button while recording, where pressing the button begins the recording and releasing the button terminates the recording.  Here's my code to do to make the "press-and-hold" functionality work (along with triggering an alert message in case the user taps the button instead of pressing and holding it):

```
Button {
            
      // The "press and hold" functionality ends when the user releases the AskAimee button, triggering the following actions.
            
      // CODE TO START RECORDING GOES HERE
            
} label: {

      // LABEL FOR THE PRESS-AND-HOLD BUTTON GOES HERE
      ButtonLabelView()
            
      // A single-tap can be used to trigger an alert to give the user instruction that a press-and-hold gesture must be used instead of a tap gesture
     
      .onTapGesture {
                    
              setupHelpTitle = "Press and Hold"
              setupHelpContent = "You need to press the button and hold it to record. Recording will stop when you release the button."
              showSetupHelp = true
          }
      }  // Tap gesture closure
}

// The "press and hold" functionality begins with a simultaneous LongPressGesture, triggering the actions in the .onEnded modifier of the gesture.
        
        .simultaneousGesture(
            LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.25)
                .onEnded({ _ in
                    
                    // CODE TO BEGIN RECORDING AFTER THE MINIMUM HOLD TIME HERE
                })
        )  // simultaneousGesture closure

        // This alert is used to provide a notification to the user about the recording function (e.g., if user tapped the button, the alert would indicate that the button needs to be pressed and held to work).
        
        .alert(isPresented: $showSetupHelp) {
            Alert(
                title: Text(setupHelpTitle),
                message: Text("\(setupHelpContent)"),
                dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"))
            )
        }
```